# How to replace a key with def value using karate framework

Tags: karate

I have a JSON file as given below:

```
{
    "lastname": {
        "displayName": "lastname"
    },
    "#(dynamicKey)": {
        "displayName": "#(dynamicKey)"
    }
}
```

When I try to read the file, the key and values are not getting updated but when I use JSON like below, value got replaced by the def values. If I give dynamic key both key and value are not getting updated. :-(

```
{
    "lastname": {
        "displayName": "lastname"
     },
     "someKey": {
        "displayName": "#(dynamicKey)"
     }
}
```

Could you please help me on how to replace dynamic key and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can handle dynamic keys. The `#(dynamicKey)` embedded-expression approach will not work.

```
* def dynamicKey = 'bar'
* def test = { someKey: 'foo' }
* test[dynamicKey] = 'baz'
* match test == { someKey: 'foo', bar: 'baz' }
```